# Google Sheets Script to search cell for string and return value

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Sheets API but do have some experience in Excel VB. What I am having troubles with is figuring out the correct syntax to do I what I could do in VB.

What I am trying to achieve in the Google sheets API is the following:

If  a particular cell first three characters matched "Old", set another variable to 3 else set the variable to 1.

In VB, you could do this like (Where A1 is the cell:

```
If Left(Sheet1!A1, 3) = "Old" Then
  aaa = 3
Else
  aaa = 1
End If
```

How would you do the same in Google sheets API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `substr`. Example below assumes you have a variable `cell` which has the appropiate cell selected.

```
if (cell.substr(0,3) == "Old") {
  aaa = 3
} else {
  aaa = 1
}
```

Which is just basic JS. [Example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3dtb9nw/)