# Update spreadsheet based on another spreadhsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm brushing up on my JS to build a project for my students and teachers. After reviewing the Apps Script documentation and questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297072/google-sheets-script-to-search-cell-for-string-and-return-value), I'm stuck producing a script to make two spreadsheets talk to one another. The Responses sheet will receive forms with the responder's last name and a selection of students from a dropdown ("connected students"). The roster sheet lists students in column B.

Upon receiving a new response (i.e. a new last row), I want to parse through the roster. If a student's name is included in the form submission (column D of the Responses sheet), I want to add the teacher's name to column D of the roster sheet.

I'm currently not getting an error message, but my test response is not mapping onto the roster. All help will be well received. See images for examples of the sheets: Mr. Cortazar submits a form that includes a student from the roster as his selection; the screen runs upon his form's submission. As a result, Cortazar's name appears next to the student from the roster who is a part of his selection, under the Adult Connections column.

```
function getData(){
      var date = new Date();
      var responsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXX').getSheetByName('Responses');
      var responsesLastRow = responsesSheet.getLastRow();    

      var teacher = responsesSheet.getRange(responsesLastRow, 3).getValue();

      var connectedStudents = responsesSheet.getRange(responsesLastRow, 4).getValue();

      var rosterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXX').getSheetByName('roster');
      var rosterLastRow = rosterSheet.getLastRow();
      var rosterArray = rosterSheet.getRange(responsesLastRow, 2).getValues()

      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < responsesLastRow; i++) {
        if (connectedStudents.substr(responsesLastRow, 4) == rosterArray[i]) {
         rosterSheet.getRange((i + 1), 3).setValue(teacher);
        }  
      }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue might be that although `rosterArray` is 2 dimensional array and the length is 1, the value and array are compared and the for loop run from 0 to `responsesLastRow`. But from your question, I cannot understand about your situation. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Question edited to show examples of the sheets. In this case, I'd like for "Cortazar" to appear on the Adult Connections column for all students that he chose in his form response.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the additional image and `I'd like for "Cortazar" to appear on the Adult Connections column for all students that he chose in his form response.`. Can you provide the input and output you expected? By this, I would like to think of your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike I appreciate the question (your English is good!). I've updated the images and their description in the question to better illustrate what I'm going for. Cortazar submits his name and chosen students in his response. This triggers the script, which updates the Adult Connections column to say Cortazar next to the student that is part of Cortazar's form response.

Comment: Thank you for replying and additional information. From your script and image, it is found `connectedStudents` and `responsesLastRow` are `Smith, John F., Stephenson, Donald J.` and 2, respectively. And `rosterArray` is `[["Waynes, Bruce"]]`. In this case, `connectedStudents.substr(responsesLastRow, 4)` is `ith,`, and this value is compared with `[["Waynes, Bruce"]]`. From this situation, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. Can you explain about it? If I misunderstood your situation, please tell me. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I understand. My goal is to turn all the names in the "Full name" column into an array ["Smith, John F.", "Waynes, Bruce"]. Then I want to compare each item in the array to the items in responsesLastRow. In this case, since responsesLastRow includes "Smith, John F." I want the form responder's name (Cortazar) to appear next to "Smith, John F." in C2 of the first image.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that I could understand about your goal. In order to test a modified script, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. If you cannot do it, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, my account is linked to my work and personal information--I'm not able to send links to sample sheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Retrieve the value of the last row from `Responses` sheet.
- Retrieve the values of the column "B" from `roster` sheet.
- You want to put the value of the column "C" of the last row of `Responses` sheet to the column "C" of `roster` sheet, when the value of the column "B" of `roster` sheet is included in the value of the column "D" of `Responses` sheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- I think that `rosterSheet.getRange(responsesLastRow, 2).getValues()` is `rosterSheet.getRange(1, 2, rosterLastRow, 1).getValues()`.

  - By this, the values of column "B" of `roster` sheet can be retrieved.
- When you check whether `Smith, John F.` is included in `Smith, John F., Stephenson, Donald J.`, you can use `indexOf()`.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var rosterArray = rosterSheet.getRange(responsesLastRow, 2).getValues()
var i;
for (i = 0; i < responsesLastRow; i++) {
  if (connectedStudents.substr(responsesLastRow, 4) == rosterArray[i]) {
   rosterSheet.getRange((i + 1), 3).setValue(teacher);
  }  
}
```

To:

```
var rosterArray = rosterSheet.getRange(1, 2, rosterLastRow, 1).getValues();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < rosterLastRow; i++) { // <--- Modified
  if (rosterArray[i][0] && connectedStudents.indexOf(rosterArray[i][0]) > -1) {
    rosterSheet.getRange((i + 1), 3).setValue(teacher);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

### Added:

- You want to add the value to the column "C" of the sheet of `roster`, when the value is existing.

About your new question, if my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

From:

```
var rosterArray = rosterSheet.getRange(responsesLastRow, 2).getValues()
var i;
for (i = 0; i < responsesLastRow; i++) {
  if (connectedStudents.substr(responsesLastRow, 4) == rosterArray[i]) {
   rosterSheet.getRange((i + 1), 3).setValue(teacher);
  }  
}
```

To:

```
var rosterArray = rosterSheet.getRange(1, 2, rosterLastRow, 2).getValues();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < rosterLastRow; i++) {
  if (rosterArray[i][0] && connectedStudents.indexOf(rosterArray[i][0]) > -1) {
    if (rosterArray[i][1] && rosterArray[i][1].indexOf(teacher) == -1) {
      rosterSheet.getRange((i + 1), 3).setValue(rosterArray[i][1] + "," + teacher);
    } else if (!rosterArray[i][1]) {
      rosterSheet.getRange((i + 1), 3).setValue(teacher);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. This adds the name from Column C of the responses sheet to Column C of the roster sheet. However, the intention is to add the teacher's name to all people in the roster who appear in the submitter's response. Currently, it only maps the submitter's name into the first name from the list.

Comment: @gonzalo2000 Thank you for replying. I noticed a modification point. So I modified it. Could you please confirm it again?

Comment: Thank you for the added insight! Should it be the case that a name is already in the cell when the script is run, is there a way to add another name (e.g. Cortazar * Smith) rather than replacing with setValue() ?

Comment: I tried the above line replacement, but it updates the name rather than add with a comma

Comment: @gonzalo2000 I added one more modified script for your new question. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @gonzalo2000 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.